# How to change the file path in a external reference cell automatically, or making a dynamic variable in a formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have a master excel file meant for monitoring of different material quantities and i get my data from other source files all in different folders.

An example of my formula: =SUMPRODUCT(--('C:\my file path directory[01.07.2023 ABC.xlsx]ABC 01.07.2023'!$C:$C=$B5),'C:\my file path directory[01.07.2023 ABC.xlsx]ABC 01.07.2023'!$E:$E)

The formula is working for me. But I realized in order for the monitoring file to capture the changes, the changes have to be made in the referenced workbook (01.07.2023 ABC.xlsx) and sheet. However, i am unable to do so as the updated value from  maybe two weeks later will be from another new workbook file with a new name
For eg, the first workbook i referenced is named 01.07.2023 ABC.xlsx
My new workbook will be named as 14.07.2023 ABC.xlsx

My monitoring file will still be taking values from  the 01.07.23 ABC.xlsx file cos the formula is not updated. I have been manually updating the data by replacing the name of the workbook using ctrl + H.

Am wondering if there is an automated way of doing so such that i can create a drop down list and pick what workbook (and sheets) to include in my formula and update the references in my monitoring file?

Or are there any ways to automate this process such that the formula will pick the lastest file in that particular folder?

Appreciate if anyone could help!!

Comment: A combination of [getting the latest document in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44906084/opening-the-youngest-file-in-a-folder-vba) with [using the reference in a formula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36227234/19353309) should do the trick unless you do want a dropdown, then you'll need to fill a listbox with the names of the workbooks found in the first link.